# How to auto populate nested associations of sails blueprint for url /model/<id>/association

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have two models Users and Chat with many to many association.

User.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
         type       : 'string'
        ,required   : true
    },

    email:{
         type   : 'string'
        ,email  : true
        ,required: true
        ,unique : true
    },
    enpassword : {
        type: 'string'
    },

    online : {
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultsTo: false
    },

    socketid: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    chats : {
      collection: 'chat',
      via: 'users',
      dominant: true
    }

};
```

Chat.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    messages : {
      collection: 'message',
      via       : 'chat',
      dominant  : true
    },
    users : {
      collection: 'user',
      via       : 'chats'
    },
  }
};
```

When I call sails blueprint /user/1/chats I am getting list of chats but users association of each chat is not populated.

How can I achieve this from Sails queries ?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `find` in the controller and doing a `.populate('users')` on the query?

Comment: Hi Joey,
URL includes the dynamic user id value like 1 in /user/1/chats. Looking for any alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. Here is a really easy way to do this.

First, require the following module.

```
var nestedPop = require('nested-pop');
```

Next, run your query.

```
getPopulatedUsers = function(req, res) {
  User.find()
  .populate('chats')
  .then(function(users) {
    return nestedPop(users, {
      chats: [
        'messages',
        'users' // I actually wouldn't recommend populating this since you already have the users
      ]
    }).then(function(users) {
      console.log(users);
      res.json(users);
    });
  });
}
```

More docs on this can be found at the following link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-pop